# Linkify with TextView

Tags: android, textview, textwatcher, linkify

I want to use Linkify with my extended TextView, but if i use Linkify in overrided setText() method fails because of endless cycle.

I found such solution, but it isn't pretty:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(bypass){
                    bypass = false;
                    return;
                }
                bypass = true;
                if(!Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS | Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES)){
                    Linkify.addLinks(textView, phoneMatcher, "tel:", null, Linkify.sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Is there a way to use Linkify on TextView without such workaround? I want that my extended TextView automatically add links if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Found a proper solution, to use

> addLinks(Spannable s, Pattern p,
>               String scheme, MatchFilter matchFilter,
>               TransformFilter transformFilter)

and then set spannable using

> setText(Spannable spannable)

method.